# net.sf.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: hibernate, java-7, hibernate-mapping, weblogic11g

I am trying to set 'Level' with some values but i get exception. Below is the version and code.

Hibernate version: 2.1

Server: Weblogic 11g

Mapping documents:

```
 <property name="Level" type="java.lang.Integer">
 <meta attribute="default-value">new java.lang.Integer(0)</meta>    
 <column name="Level" not-null="true" length="3" />    
 </property>
```

Code:

```
public Pol fillPol(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
      Pol p = new Pol();
      p.setLevel(new Integer(rs.getInt("setLevel")));
      if (rs.IsNull()) {
          p.setLevel(null);
      }
      return p;
  }
```

Exception i get

```
Caused by: net.sf.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value
```

Please help.

Comment: The code you've shown has nothing to do with Hibernate. You're using plain ResultSet in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have a DB <-> Java datatype mismatch.

To fix this check:

- DB column. If it's allowed to have null values.
- Java type. If it's
  primitive type or not.

Try the following:

```
  public Pol fillPol(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
      Pol p = new Pol();
      p.setLevel(new Integer(rs.getInt("setLevel")));
      if (rs.IsNull()) {
          p.setLevel(Integer.valueOf(0)); //according to the mapping you're not setting it to null, but to zero.
      }
      return p;
  }
```

Comment: We have this working fine with OC4j server but weblogic is giving the exception

Comment: do you have the same DB?

Comment: Yes. Have the same DB

Comment: thanks for your help, can you please advise if  <meta attribute="default-value">new java.lang.Integer(0)</meta> is a proper way of setting the default integer value? im using JDK1.7 with hibernate2. Does autoboxing plays any role for the discussed exception?